# Comparing different size arrays - D3 JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have two arrays, namely info and connect.

They look like this.

```
{
info[
{
"name":"a",
"X" : 24
},
{
"name":"b",
"X" : 30
},
{
"name":"c",
"X" : 14
},
{
"name":"d",
"X" : 45
}
],
"connect":[
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "b" 
},
{
"name1": "b", "name2": "a"
},
{
"name1": "c", "name2": "a"
},
{
"name1": "d", "name2": "a"
},
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "c"
},
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "d"
},
{
"name1": "b", "name2": "d"
},
{
"name1": "b", "name2": "c"
},
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "b"
}
]
}
```

As we can see, they both have different sizes. I want to compare the strings name1 and name2 with name in info and want to sum the two X values.

For example, if name1 is 'a' and name2 is 'b' then I want to get the sum of 24 and 30 which is 54.

I'm trying something like this:

```
 for(i=0; i<connect.length; i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<info.length;j++)
                    if(connect[i].name1 == info[j].name && connect[i].name2 == info[j].name)
                        {
                                                }
}
```

But it is not comparing correctly. I'm trying to solve this. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please Note that, I haven't written the operation of summing the values. I want to try different operations along with summation. So, I haven't written the operations. But this isn't comparing properly. Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a hash of lookups for your `info` values. Then, `map` over the `connect` array to calculate the sums based on that hash. See if the following works for you.

```js
const info = [
{
"name":"a",
"X" : 24
},
{
"name":"b",
"X" : 30
},
{
"name":"c",
"X" : 14
},
{
"name":"d",
"X" : 45
}
];

const connect = [
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "b" 
},
{
"name1": "b", "name2": "a"
},
{
"name1": "c", "name2": "a"
},
{
"name1": "d", "name2": "a"
},
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "c"
},
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "d"
},
{
"name1": "b", "name2": "d"
},
{
"name1": "b", "name2": "c"
},
{
"name1": "a", "name2": "b"
}
];

const infoLookup = info.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.name] = el.X;
  return acc;
}, {});

const connectSums = connect.map(({name1, name2}) => ({
  name1,
  name2,
  sum: infoLookup[name1] + infoLookup[name2]
}));

console.log(connectSums);
```